Parsing AWS Textract response - Using amazon-textract-response-parser
I'm sending a table image to aws textract it returns a response I tried making use of this package https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-response-parser but for some reason I've been getting this error
throw new Error(`pageNum ${pageNum} must be between 1 and ${this._pages.length}`);
            ^

Error: pageNum 1 must be between 1 and 0
    at TextractDocument.pageNumbe

My implementation to sending the image
const aws = require("aws-sdk");

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "",
  secretAccessKey: "",
  region: "us-west-2",
});

const textract = new aws.Textract();

module.exports = async (buffer) => {
  const params = {
    Document: {
      /* required */
      Bytes: buffer,
    },
    FeatureTypes: ["TABLES"],
  };

  const request = textract.analyzeDocument(params);
  const data = await request.promise();

  if (data && data.Blocks) {
    return data.Blocks;
  }

  // in case no blocks are found return undefined
  return undefined;
};


Here is how I was using the package
const fs = require("fs");
const textractScan = require("./test");
const {
  TextractDocument,
  TextractIdentity,
} = require("amazon-textract-response-parser");

(async () => {
  // var data = fs.readFileSync("./IMG_0201.jpg");
  // const results = await textractScan(data);
  fs.readFile("./src/samples/aws-sample-table.json", (err, resBuffer) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const doc = new TextractDocument(JSON.parse(resBuffer));
    const page = doc.pageNumber(1);
    const table = page.tableAtIndex(0);

    // Index cells by row, column, or both:
    const headerStrs = table.cellsAt(1, null)?.map((cell) => cell.text);
    const firstColCells = table.cellsAt(null, 1);
    const targetCell = table.cellAt(2, 4);

    // Iterate over rows/cells:
    for (const row of table.iterRows()) {
      for (const cell of row.iterCells()) {
        console.log(cell.text);
      }
    }
  });
})();


Below is the output that I got
https://pastebin.com/dZgWFVAv (The text response was to long to add here)
